# Android: Scroll or resize Canvas on a CustomView

Tags: android, scrollview, android-canvas

I have a custom view where there is a Canvas drawn with circles and lines. My problem is that once transferred to the tablet look cropped image and not real. Is there a way to resize the CustomView and fit the screen automatically, or even scroll the image.
A bit of code:

```
public class CustomView extends View {

    Paint pPaint;
    Paint cPaint;
    Paint textPaint;

    int w,h;
    int px=150,py=150;
    int cx=450,cy=150;
    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);


        pPaint=new Paint(); // pennello
        pPaint.setColor(Color.RED);  
        pPaint.setAntiAlias(true); 

        cPaint=new Paint(); // pennello
        cPaint.setColor(Color.CYAN);     
        cPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        textPaint=new Paint(); // pennello
        textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);     
        textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

    }



<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.abstractargument.CustomView
            android:id="@+id/customView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: why dont you just set your LinearLayout to fill_parent? Then your custom view will have size of your screen also

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.html

Comment: so it does not work, i don't understand

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.abstractargument.CustomView
            android:id="@+id/customView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

Comment: The RelativeLayout is useless, you can put the layout parameters in the LinearLayout and leave out the RelativeLayout. Then, like Marko said, set layout_height/width to match_parent, and it should work. "orientation = vertical" doesn't do anything if there's only one child view.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested but the result does not change unfortunately. I could set up a ScrollView with canvas?